# Setting Up Neovim for C++ with CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, ide, neovim

I'm using coc for code-completion and ale for linting my c++ files, this works fine when I have all my headers and source files in the same directory, however when I have a CMake project with the typical `include` & `src` directories (for headers and .cpp files respectively) this setup fails to realize that my headers are in the `include` directory and so the linting and code completion dont work.
Any help in configuring my neovim setup to handle this project structure, or suggestions of different plugins which would do what I want would be much appreciated.

Comment: "or suggestions of different plugins which would do what I want" is off-topic because you're asking us for recommendations. Instead, you need to do the research, find what looks good, use it, then ask a specific question about that particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check CMake's documentation regarding [CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html).

Here is part of my `.nvimrc` for example:

```
nnoremap <F5> :wa <bar> :set makeprg=cd\ build\ &&\ cmake\ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug\ -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1\ ../view\ &&\ cmake\ --build\ . <bar> :compiler gcc <bar> :make <CR>
```

This generates the `compile_commands.json` file which is read by the various [ALE Supported Languages and Tools](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/supported-tools.md).

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice Plugin [cmake4vim](https://github.com/ilyachur/cmake4vim) which works really fine.

You can e.g. set the name of the build path, run/edit config (incl. the `ccmake` tool), build within vim, jump to next error, ...